# Gitlab: Login leads to infinite redirect loop

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, gitlab

since yesterday I'm trying to install Gitlab on my homeserver, but so far I haven't had any luck in getting it running :(

I installed it on Ubuntu 14.04 by using the available packages from the Gitlab site at: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404

Then I configured it to use the external domain https://gitlab.example.com (changed for security reasons) and I want to proxy it via Apache using a reverse proxy with SSL.

So far I can see the login page and browse around, but when I try to login using the default username and password I end up in an infinite loop of redirects and I can't find the reason why. I tried every solution I found until now, but none of them are working for me.

I did some changes in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
unicorn['port'] = 8890 # needed, since the port 8080 was already in use
nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['*']
nginx['listen_port'] = 8888
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

My Apache 2.4 vHost is configured like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gitlab.example.com

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.example.com-error.log

  Redirect / https://gitlab.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName gitlab.example.com

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.example.com-error.log

  RequestHeader set Host "gitlab.example.com"
  RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Ssl on
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-For %{REMOTE_IP}e
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/mycert/server.key
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/mycert/server.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

And the log at `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log` tells me this:

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
Started GET "/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Redirected to https://gitlab.example.com/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
Started GET "/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Redirected to https://gitlab.example.com/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
Started GET "/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Redirected to https://gitlab.example.com/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
Started GET "/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Redirected to https://gitlab.example.com/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
Started GET "/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Redirected to https://gitlab.example.com/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
Started GET "/" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by RootController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2015-09-24 22:32:40 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Redirected to https://gitlab.example.com/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Maybe someone of you has an idea why this is happening?

Bets regards,
Benni

Comment: Did you get it running? Btw. it looks strange that you didn't disable nginx when you want to use GitLab through apache.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Gitlab is running now after I installed an update, but the redirect loop still exists in all browsers except IE 11. I never tried to disable Nginx, since the Reverse Proxy needs another server in the background.

Comment: After upgrading GitLab to version 8.8.3 I can now login in all browsers and the endless loop of redirects doesn't happen anymore. I have no idea what or why those happened, but at least my problem is now solved.